# WebStorm doesn't recognise use of components inside JSX

Tags: reactjs, react-native, webstorm, jsx, eslint

Say I'm importing a component:

```
const MyComponent   = require('./components/MyComponent');
```

And then use it inside JSX block:

```
const App = props => (<MyComponent/>)
```

I get an error from Eslint in WebStorm:

```
'MyComponent' is assigned a value but never used (no-unused-vars)
```

How do I make WebStorm to understand I'm using this variable?

Comment: Require is usually for flat file loading. You should use `import MyComponent from './components/MyComponent'` instead. Try it out :)

Comment: @cbll same error when using it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not WebStorm but ESLint that doesn't recognize your JSX variable. Do you have eslint-plugin-react installed? I guess you are missing the `jsx-uses-vars` rule. See https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/2156, https://github.com/hyperapp/hyperapp/issues/557 for some hints

Comment: @Iena thanks! now no error, but now I get "Unused constant MyComponent"

Comment: I'm getting the "Unused constant..." warning as well, not from my linting config, but from WebStorm itself.